# How to use cometd cometProvider?

Tags: cometd

i am trying to use cometd in my web application , but i am getting below exception 
Unknown provider: cometdProvider <- cometd <- chat ?
i have added

```html
<script  src="bower_components/angular-cometd/angular-cometd.js"></script>
<script  src="bower_components/angular-cometd/angular-cometd-reload.js"></script>
<script  src="bower_components/cometd/cometd.js"></script>
<script  src="bower_components/cometd/ReloadExtension.js"></script>
```

my JS file

```
app.controller('chat', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$http','cometd', function($scope, $timeout, $http,cometd)
```

```html
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-javascript-angular</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-oort</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-websocket-javax-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

please tell me how to resolve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are using the official [CometD code](https://github.com/cometd/cometd), because the official CometD does not have the concept of a provider.

Please have a read at the [official documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/) to get started with CometD.

Comment: i have download CometD from the same location. please read updated Question.

Comment: Please have a look at the working Angular 1.x CometD demo chat by running the CometD demo [as explained in the documentation](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_installation_demos).

Comment: is it mandatory to have keystore.jks file ? and do we need to take any special step to generate this file.

Comment: The keystore is necessary if you want to use TLS within the JVM, otherwise it's not necessary.

Comment: thanks , i am able to resolve above problem but now i am getting "http://localhost:8090/cometd-demo/chat/cometd/handshake" is not found ? how do i deploy handshake ?

Comment: I guess you are requesting the wrong URL, so you probably have the CometD URL configured wrong in your application.

Comment: i have corrected the URL , now i  am getting "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8090/cometd-demo/cometd' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404" ? what could be the reason ? i am using tomcat.